# How to get the old value of a textarea

Tags: javascript, dom-events, textarea

That's it. How can I get the old  value of a textarea in order to compare it with a new value?. The current value becomes the old value after triggering an event (say, a keyup event).

I have seen some solutions, for example, using cookies to record the old value and the new value, however, such solution doesn't work in my case because of the type of manipulation I want to perform later.

Hopefully, there is a suggestion which works better than that.

**UPDATE**:

After following some suggestions from @drachenstern, @Matthew, @Peter, I ended up with something like this

```
var startTimer = null;
var oldValue;
$("#textarea").keydown($.debounce( 1000, true, function(){
oldValue = $("#textarea").val();
}
));

$("#textarea").keyup(function(){
if(startTimer) clearTimeout(startTimer);
startTimer = setTimeout(function(){
var newValue = $("#textarea").val();
d = // here a clever comparison
oldValue = newValue;
},2000);
})
```

By the way, `$.debounce` is a function from the jQuery throttle / debounce plugin.

This does exactly what I want, however, I'd like to obtain the variable `d` outside of setTimeout function and of keyup function, in order to use it elsewhere. However, clearTimeout seems to be tricky when it comes to return values. Any way to get the value of the `d`?.

Comment: Make a global variable (yes, I know global variables are evil) and assign d to that variable.

Comment: @Peter: Only option available?. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: I'm sure it isn't the only option, but it's the only one that I can think of right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var oldValue = document.getElementById("textareaid").value;

document.getElementById("textareaid").onchange = function(){
  var newValue = this.value;
  //Compare oldValue and newValue
  oldValue = newValue;
}
```

Comment: make oldvalue an array and set keys with some sort of stamping, say arrayOldValue[version_1] = initialValue and then keep on increasing the version_1 to version_n and you may even have support for version-ing

Comment: @Peter: Nice, but I need to use that // Compare oldValue and newValue stuff outside of the function. Any way to accomplish that?

Comment: @Kumar: Well, in my case, trying to keep all values would be too much. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: @Robert Smith Put the code you need to use in a function and call that function.

Comment: @Peter: Uhm, after trying your suggestion, I think maybe I didn't understand it correctly. I will update the question to show what is the actual problem.