# clearTimeout & setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, jquery-events

As a follow up of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215480/how-to-get-the-old-value-of-a-textarea), I'd like to know why this is not working

```
$("#textarea").keydown(function(){
oldValue = $("#textarea").val();
});
$("#textarea").keyup(function(){
var startTimer = null;
if(startTimer) clearTimeout(startTimer);
startTimer = setTimeout(function(){
var newValue = $("#textarea").val();
// get something out of the comparison
alert(something) // alert the comparison
  oldValue = newValue;

},2000);
```

The required behavior would be to get an alert message only when the user hasn't typed anything for 2 seconds. It works as for the comparison part, however, it doesn't stop the alert message when I keep typing as it should. Instead, I get the same number of alerts as the number of keys pressed.
I tried a version of this creating and deleting cookies, which it worked fine. What is wrong in this particular case?

Comment: var startTimer = null; if(startTimer) clearTimeout(startTimer); //condition can never be true...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're getting a new `startTimer` (and initializing it to `null`) on each call to your `keyup` handler. Try declaring it in an outside scope:

```
(function() {
    var startTimer = null;
    var oldValue; // Declare this too, so it isn't global

    $("#textarea").keydown(function(){
        oldValue = $("#textarea").val();
    });
    $("#textarea").keyup(function(){
        if(startTimer) {
            clearTimeout(startTimer);
        }
        startTimer = setTimeout(function(){
            var newValue = $("#textarea").val();
            // get something out of the comparison
            alert(something) // alert the comparison
            oldValue = newValue;
        },2000);
    });
})();
```

Comment: Of course. That solves the problem. It doesn't produces the behavior I want, but definitely solves this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you really want is to look at using either a throttling or a debouncing style function. Here's a fella that has written one that works with *or without* the use of jQuery, and can do exactly what you're asking for. I would give it a try.

> http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/
>
> Throttling
>   Using jQuery throttle / debounce, you can pass a delay and function to $.throttle to get a new function, that when called repetitively, executes the original function (in the same context and with all arguments passed through) no more than once every delay milliseconds.
>
> Throttling can be especially useful for rate limiting execution of handlers on events like resize and scroll. Just take a look at the following usage example or the working throttling examples to see for yourself!

And also see the wonderful workflow images he uses. I won't hotlink, but it's worth a read on the article to see what library already exists so you can save yourself some time.

Comment: 1+. That looks promising. I will definitely take a look at that. However, I'd like to know why I'm not getting the intended behavior in my code.

Comment: @Robert ~ You're more than welcome. I knew somebody (in this case Matthew) would be along to debug the actual issue you're facing, but I stumbled across the link I provided a few weeks back on another issue and figured I would pay it forward on the help. I'm all for using framework independent javascript to help me along so I don't have to rewrite anything, ya know?

Comment: I agree. Furthermore, let me tell you that your suggestion actually did what I wanted (along with Matthew correction) by using a $.debounce in the keydown function. Thanks!.